# What does "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" mean in python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i try use `print str`

```
 print str(i) + '/' + str(len(pass_list))

SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

Comment: `print` is not a statement anymore in **python3**, it's a function. So you have to use the parenthesis to call it.

Comment: It means that the syntax you used is invalid.

Comment: The error message is clear. Yes, its a syntax error

Comment: As the name indicates, your syntax is wrong. In Python 3, `print` is a function. So you should use it like this: `print(some_string)`

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you want to print should be enclosed in parenthesis.

```
print(str(i) + '/' + str(len(pass_list)))
```